# What Design Pattern is Useful for Communicating With Database

Tags: java, database, design-patterns

I need a Design Pattern that is good for communicating with a Database.

I want an object that is used by different subsystems of the software to communicate with the Database. This object will have all the MySQL queries in functions.

For example:

```
class DatabaseController
{
   getAllUsers()
   {
     // Access the Database and get all the UserNames.
   }

   findUserID(String id)
   {
      // Look in the User Table in MySQL database.
   }

   findItem(String itemName)
   {
      // Look in the item's table in MySQL database.
   }
}
```

I was thinking of a Singleton, so that I would provide just one entry point to the DatabaseController.

**Is there superior design pattern that will allow other classes to communicate with the DatabaseController and has functionality designed for communicating with Databases?**

Different parts of the software will call, for example.

```
class ItemController
{
  findItem(String itemName)
  {
     DatabaseController.findItem(itemName);
  }
}
```

[EDIT]
I am looking for something to write myself, possibly looking at a tutorial, and in Java.

Comment: `Unit of Work` with `Repository Pattern`. However I just know the concept but not the implementation / best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the database I think but check out the Entity Framework and also the Data Repository Pattern.

They are the two I always use on any project involving a database.

I wouldn't use a singleton as a DB pattern.  I might us it to store static data coming from a database though.

Comment: If a database design pattern "depends on the database" then it isn't a good pattern. The whole point of such a pattern is to decouple database access/implementation/usage from business requirements. The repository pattern gives you an interface for interacting with the database without providing you with the specific implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

Data Access Object is a core J2EE pattern for accessing DB data, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have implemented a database 'abstraction' using static classes for the database and it's tables. This has led to a complete mess and loads of work. This is definitely not the way to go.

Since you're using Java, you should look into JPA. Using JPA with a Repository pattern works like a charm. You map your entities (domain models) to database tables and you don't have to write a lot of queries. If you would write queries, you'd write JQL queries. Those are abstract queries and are database agnostic.